# Spy thriller book with a human sub-class

Tags: story-identification

New book from the library several years ago - not a single word of the title

This book sets off like a tech spy thriller but after a few chapters you realise it isn't quite . 
There is, particularly in Europe and the Basque regions, an underclass that are commonly known as 'the sh*t people'.
They've been side by side with modern man for thousands of years

The story is about protagonist and his girl hurriedly searching through Basque hill villages for some sh*t people leader (can't remember why)
They are known as sh*t people because they are typically scrawnier, plainer looking and a lot unhealthier than standard humans. Shorter lifespan and poorly paid jobs

One feature I remember is the protagonists knew they'd found a new area heavily populated with sh*t people because there were lots of graves outside the local churchyards (no sanctified ground for sh*t people) and, I think, usually signs outside bars and cafes banning them

Can't remember how the story ends or anything. I remember this was a fairly thick book, a "summer blockbuster" thing

EDIT UPDATE: LOOKING AT ANSWERS GIVEN I REALISE NOW THIS IS JUST A SPY THRILLER. I GENUINELY THOUGHT WHEN READING IT THAT IT WAS "PARALLEL EARTH" DUE TO THE SUB-CLASS OF PEOPLE. I DIDN'T REALISE THEY ACTUALLY EXISTED -SORRY

Comment: Sounds thematically similar to Harry Turtledove's "A Different Flesh", but that one is set in the US.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Different_Flesh

Comment: Are you certain of the epithet for the marginalized group? It should be easy to turn up in a search if it’s correct.

Comment: The in-story obscene name for the underclass is a useful detail in this story-identification question, but surely — even partially obscured with an asterisk — one mention is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If LSerni is correct, and this is about the Cagot people, the most likely candidate I've found would be *[The Marks Of Cain](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7576543-the-marks-of-cain)* by Tom Knox. Its plotline involves a young lawyer named David Martinez and his attempt to fulfill his grandfather's bequest that involves following a map through Basque territories and then showing the map to someone at the end. There is a separate plotline involving a London journalist named Simon Quinn who is investigating murders of people who may have been in involved in Nazi camps in the Basque region.

I have not read the book myself, but from combing through the reviews, it looks like the payoff is that the Cagots may be proof of a 1907 theorem that humanity had developed into sub-species, a theory pursued by the Nazi party to justify their treatment of the Jews, disproved and rejected by the Catholic church in later years in an attempt to bring the Cagots back into the fold, and then again pursued by a group of Jewish people looking to marginalize non-Jewish people in Jerusalem. The phrase "shit people" is indeed used to refer to the Cagots several times in the book.

From searches in Google Books, David is accompanied by a woman named Amy, and there is a plotline involving the graves and them having been desecrated. I'm not certain what her relationship to him is. And indeed, unless there's something more substantive behind the "genetic curse" that a lot of the summaries mention, this is not Sci-Fi or Fantasy, if this is the book.

On a second look through your question, this probably cannot be your book, because it wasn't published until 2010 while you read your book in the 80s. That said, I'll keep this up on the off chance it helps someone else.

Comment: Sorry. I had landed on Tom Knox's book myself, but somehow your answer had not even appeared in my browser (I'd forgotten the tab open in Firefox), so I had posted an essentially identical answer to yours a few minutes ago.

Comment: @LSemi: Oh, no worries. Frankly, if you want to undelete your answer, I'll delete mine. Yours is much more complete.